# Exists method in UFT produces General Run Error when object not found

Tags: qtp, uft14

I'm running a UFT script (using UFT 14.51 on a Windows 7 machine) that sometimes runs on its own and is sometimes called as an action by another script, so at a particular point it may or may not have a particular window open. (This script is testing a SAP GUI application; it's not Web-based.)

I've tried putting the object name directly into the Exists line instead of defining it with Set oObject.

I've tried re-adding the object to the repository.

The code looks like this:

````
Set sObject =  <repository object>
If sObject.Exist(1) Then
    ```do something```  
End if
````

If the specified object is visible, this code works. However, when it's not, instead of skipping the code the program dies with a general run error.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the run error says.  I could be you haven't properly identified the object.  Are you using descriptive programming?
For example if you have an object defined that's say a Java Button, when you reference it you have to give the pull path.  So:

````
Set sObject =  JavaWindow("the window").JavaButton(<repository object>)
If sObject.Exist(1) Then
    ```do something```  
End If
````

If that doesn't work, you can add an Eval to the object.  So:

````
Set sObject =  JavaWindow("the window").JavaButton(<repository object>)
If Eval(sObject).Exist(1) Then
    ```do something```  
End If
````

Answer (score 0):

What does the Run Error says?
Try to wrap the "If" statement with:
On Error Resume Next
If .... Then

End If
' check here if Err.Description <> "", it might hint you what is wrong.
On Error Goto 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Function ExisteElemento(ByRef test_object)

    On Error Resume Next
    ExisteElemento = test_object.Exist(1)
    If Err.Number <>0 Then
        'print Err.Number &" - decripcion " & Err.Description
        ExisteElemento= False
    End If
    On Error Goto 0
End Function
RegisterUserFunc "MobileLabel","ExisteElemento","ExisteElemento"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).